# Soft body sticking to collision object

Tags: physics, soft-body

I have been trying to make a soft body animation but they keep sticking to the box they fall into.

I've tried as much as I could think of and haven't seen much about this topic online. I feel like it's something really small that I just missed.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I got it! I went to the collision object and turned up 'Outer' to .5 and now it's working fine!

Comment: It would be great if you could elaborate on *how* and *why* changing the **Outer** setting improved the simulation.

Comment: I just started messing around with random settings and it worked. I don't really know _how_ or _why_ but I found it on the [Blender manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/physics/collision.html) and it just says "Size of the outer collision zone."

Answer (score 1):

you can change the outer setting in the physics tab. this changes the size of the collision box and will stop the object from sticking

Answer (score 0):

I have found that many softbody and sticking problems can be solved by increasing the scale of the meshes in the scene.